# Return all results from left table that join, as well as missing rows that the right table can fill in

Tags: sql, select, join

I have an issue where I am trying to return all rows from one table and at the same time fill in data gaps with another table if it exists there. Currently I have working SQL and this is a simple example to show what I am doing.

```
SELECT    a.timestamp, 
          number 
FROM      tablea a WITH (nolock) 
UNION 
SELECT     b.timestamp, 
           number 
FROM       tablea a WITH (nolock) 
RIGHT JOIN tableb b WITH (nolock) 
ON         a.timestamp = b.timestamp 
WHERE      a.timestamp IS NULL
```

With some example data this produces this result, which is what I want. (Sorry about the formatting)

```
| TableA |                    | TableB |               | Result |
| 2017-7-24 | 1 |             | 2017-7-24 | 2 |        | 2017-7-24 | 1 |
| 2017-7-26 | 2 |             | 2017-7-25 | 3 |        | 2017-7-25 | 3 |
| 2017-7-27 | 2 |             | 2017-7-27 | 6 |        | 2017-7-26 | 2 |
                                                       | 2017-7-27 | 2 |
```

This works as is, I'm just wondering if there is a different way to produce the desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coalesce`ing the results would give you a much cleaner (and probably more efficient) query:

```
SELECT     COALESCE(a.timestamp, b.timestamp) AS timestamp,
           COALESCE(a.number, b.number) AS number
FROM       tablea a WITH (nolock) 
RIGHT JOIN tableb b WITH (nolock) 
ON         a.timestamp = b.timestamp
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was hoping for. A much cleaner looking query and according to the execution plan is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM TAbleA
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TableB b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM TableA a
   WHERE a.timestamp = b.timestamp
```

### )

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TableB
WHERE timestamp NOT IN (
   SELECT timestamp FROM TableA
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TableA 
UNION
SELECT * FROM TableB
WHERE timestamp NOT IN (SELECT timestamp FROM TableA)
```